# Using regression instead of classification for multi class classification

Tags: python-3.x, classification, regression, random-forest

I have a multi class classification problem. I am using random forest classifier. My boss has asked if it is possible to also view our problem with regression. I understand that for a classification task, it is of course better to use a classifier, but is it possible to implement a regression model.

My data is as such:

I have a dataset consisting of software requirements, these are rated as either 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5.

I am then creating a feature matrix to use for training the model to make predictions on the class, with 10 features such as: num_words, num_sentences, num_syllables, weak_words, flesh_idx etc

My model works quite well with 93% accuracy.

Is there a way I can view this problem using regression? Such that the model would make predictions such as 1.5 for example, where the prediction doesn't fall into the class 1 or 2 but somewhere in the middle? Or maybe 2.2, 3.3 etc as opposed to 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5?

I guess the reason is just to see if we can see the software requirement scores in a continuous way.

Answer (score 1):

try Softmax regression (or multinomial logistic regression) with [mxnet](https://gluon.mxnet.io/chapter02_supervised-learning/softmax-regression-scratch.html) or  with [tensorflow](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/softmax-regression-using-tensorflow/)

Answer (score 1):

The way you can use regression in classification problems is with Logistic Regressions. You can use this individually to classify 1 vs not 1, 2 vs not 2, and so on for each classification (don't do this), or use Softmax that in simple words, weights each class and returns a probability for each given class, then you just pick the one with the `max` probability and that will be your predicted class. There are a lot of neural networks that use `softmax` when working with mutli-class classification.
Here is a great article from `scikit-learn's` documentation:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neural_networks_supervised.html

Comment: thank you, is it possible to have an output that would be for example: a given software requirement and the result would be rating of 4.3 as opposed to a rating of 4 when using a classifier?  I think what I am thinking of is not possible though. I will have a read up about softmax and maybe it will be clearer

Comment: No, you would need regression for that, not logistic one. The output of softmax, if you have 5 classes will be an array consisting of the probability of each class: [0.02,0.01,0.002,0.10,0.868]. So the prediction for that input data will be class 5 with a probability of 86,8%, second best, class 4 with probability 10% and so on...